# HMR does not work for some projects in nrwl nx

Tags: webpack-hmr, hot-module-replacement, nrwl, nrwl-nx

I have a react application with some libraries like a seperate UI components library configured with nx. HMR doesnt work for ui library project.
When I make a change to the components in the folder declared as `projectType:"application"` in workspace.json, I just see the changes in browser. But when I make a change to the ones declared as `projectType:"library"`, the page refreshes (after I see the `[HMR] bundle rebuilding` message in the console)`

I've attached the sample configuration: https://gist.github.com/trkaplan/33e93e7cfd46c8a8690dfdecfe3ab63e